# Winter Bash - no Greeter hat

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash-2015

On this Post:

[Click on link using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350964/click-on-link-using-vba)

- I did edit it
- I did upvote it
- Its his first Post

I didn't get the [Greeter](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/greeter) hat. Did i miss something?.

Additional Information: That one upvote also triggered another hat ([A New Hope](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/a-new-hope)). I did get the A New Hope hat, but maybe that caused a bug? (one upvote - two hats)

Comment: @nicael No. I got that hat on a site where I don't have edit privileges.

Answer (score 3):

The Greeter hat also has these requirements not explicitly stated in its description:

- Edit and upvote must take place within an hour of each other, in either order
- Edit must affect post body (Pops was 99% sure about this one)

in addition to the "official" requirements:

- Edit and upvote new user's first post
- Must have been posted during Winter Bash

I learned this via [email from Pops](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/32836?m=26406318#26406318).

In the example given, your edit does affect the body of the post, but maybe it wasn't made within 1 hour of your vote.

Comment: Indeed,  the edit was approved in 8:19, the vote was cast on 9:45

Comment: Is it the time of the edit that counts or does an edit by a sub-*autoedit approval* rep holder get timed at the point of approval?  Obviously the Hat won't be awarded until that approval occurs...